# Complete all the task in a ViewController before jumping to another in Xcode8 Swift 3

Tags: swift, web-services, task, xcode8

So, I'm still working on with my poem mobile project.. I'm working on this login module. What's happening here is that it jumps from one ViewController to another ViewController.. maybe it's because of the task? Is there any way to finish all the tasks in the first ViewController before jumping to the second ViewController (TimelineViewController)? Like something to stop it from going to the TimelineViewController if the task in the first ViewController is not yet finish?

I hope someone can help me solve this.. :( Thank you in advance!

This is my ViewController code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtusername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtpassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!
    var returnVal:String? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

       @IBAction func btnLogin_Tapped(sender: UIButton) {

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.6/Test/login.php")!
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url as URL)
        let bodyData = "username=\(txtusername.text!)&password=\(txtpassword.text!)"

        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


      //  NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main){(response, data, error) in
            //print(response)
      //  }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
        {
            data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print ("Error = \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                return
            }
            if let response = response {
                print ("Response = \(response)")
            }
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print ("Response data = \(responseString)")
            }

            //Converting response to NSDictionary
            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments),
                let responseObject = json as? String,
                let returnValidation = responseObject as? String else {
                    print("did not validate")
                    return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async()
            {


                self.returnVal = returnValidation
                print("RETURN VALUE: \(self.returnVal!)")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signinSegue", sender: self)
            }
        }


        task.resume()


    }

    func AlertMessage(titleA: String, messageA: String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleA, message: messageA, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){(UIAlertAction)-> Void in }
        alert.addAction(alertAction)
        present(alert,  animated: true){() -> Void in}
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "signinSegue")
        {
            if(self.returnVal != nil)
            {

                if(self.returnVal! == "true")
                {
                let viewController = segue.destination as! TimelineViewController

                viewController.passedValue = self.returnVal!
                    viewController.viewDidLoad()

                }
                else if (self.returnVal! == "false")
                {
                    print("Incorrect Password!")
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("Empty")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

This is my TimelineViewController code

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation

    struct Poem {
        let poemTitle: String
        let poemBody: String

        init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
            guard let poemTitle = dictionary["Title"] as? String,
                let poemBody = dictionary["Body"] as? String else {
                    print("Did not find fullName/Bio")
                    return nil
            }

            self.poemTitle = poemTitle
            self.poemBody = poemBody
        }
    }

    class TimelineViewController: UIViewController  {

        @IBOutlet weak var contentTableView: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var poemBodyText: UITextView!
        @IBOutlet weak var poemTitleText: UILabel!

       var poems = [Poem]()
        var passedValue:String? = nil

        @IBOutlet weak var oPostBtn: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            if(passedValue != nil)
            {
                getPoems()
            }
            else {
                print("Empty")

            }

        }

        func getPoems()
        {
            let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.6/Test/feed1.php")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)

            request.httpMethod = "GET"


             let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
            {
                    data, response, error in

                    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                        print("Error = \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                        return
                    }
                    if let response = response {
                        print("Response = \(response)")
                    }
                    if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
                        print ("Response data = \(responseString)")
                    }

                        //Converting response to NSDictionary
                        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data),
                    let responseObject = json as? [String:Any],
                            let returnPoems = responseObject["returnPoems"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
                                print ("Did not find return Poems")
                                return
                    }
                        print (returnPoems)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.poems = returnPoems.flatMap { Poem(dictionary: $0) }
                            self.contentTableView.reloadData() }
            }
            task.resume()

        }

      /*  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }*/
                   func AlertMessage(titleA: String, messageA: String)
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleA, message: messageA, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){(UIAlertAction)-> Void in }
                alert.addAction(alertAction)
                present(alert, animated: true){() -> Void in}
            }



        @IBAction func aPostBtn(_ sender: Any) {
            var count = 0
            while(count < 2)
            {
                //print("RESPONSE!!! : \(poemTitle[count])")
                count = count + 1;
            }

        }

    }

    extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           guard let cell = contentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PoemTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? PoemTableViewCell else
           {
                fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PoemTableViewCell")
            }
            let poem = poems[indexPath.row]

            cell.poemTitleText?.text = poem.poemTitle
            cell.poemBodyText?.text = poem.poemBody


        //   cell.textLabel?.text = poem.poemTitle
         //   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = poem.poemBody

            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return poems.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

           let poem = poems[indexPath.row]
            print(poem)

        }

    }
```

Comment: I already told you not to call `viewDidLoad`. Instead of listening, you deleted your question and my answer. Why don't you try listening?

Comment: I actually listened. I just used the same code from before. viewDidLoad wasn't even my real issue. I deleted my question because I feel like it wasn't the issue after hours of thinking, sorry.

Comment: @Nadz Did my answer help you?

Comment: yes, it has something to do with segue. What I did is perform segue manually and had to add shouldperformsegue. Thanks for your help :) @nyg

Comment: @Nadz Ok, great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `btnLogin_Tapped` remove `DispatchQueue.main.async()`. I don't see why you would need this. It creates a new queue and execute the code inside it asynchronously.

Also remove `viewController.viewDidLoad()`. You should never call `viewDidLoad` yourself, it is called automatically when the new view controller appears.

Another thing that might be causing a problem is if you've created a segue in your Storyboard (Ctrl + drag) from the login button to your `TimelineViewController`. You should remove it as you perform the segue at the end of `btnLogin_Tapped`.